# Send Value From onPostExecute() to Activity is always NULL

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-asynctask

I created this class:

```
public class GetAddressPositionTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Integer, LatLng> {
    //...
}
```

It has the below function in it:

```
@Override
    public void onPostExecute(LatLng result) {
        Log.i("GEOCODE", result.toString());

        super.onPostExecute(result);

        Intent i = new Intent(this.mainContxt , MapsActivity.class);

        i.putExtra("latlng" , result);

        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

        this.mainContxt.startActivity(i);
    }
```

I am trying to send data to the Activity called MapsActivity from the onPostExecute method.

---

In MapsActivity I have before onCreate this:

```
LatLng position = new LatLng(34.6767, 33.04455);
```

---

My onCreate:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

            if (getIntent() != null) {
                Intent intent = getIntent();

                if (getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("latlng")!= null) {
                    position = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("latlng");
                }
                else {
                    Log.d("NULL?", "position is empty!");
                }
            } else {
            }

            MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.
                            map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }
```

---

This is my onMapReady that created the pin with the position that I initialized and when you type an address and press the search button, it calls the above class that has the onPost function and trying to pin a location in the map if the position is not null.

```
@Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap map) {
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 13));
        CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);
        map.animateCamera(zoom);

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .title("Shop")
                .snippet("Is this the right location?")
                .position(position))
                .setDraggable(true);

        // map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new PopupAdapter(getLayoutInflater()));
        map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);
        map.setOnMarkerDragListener(this);

        ImageButton search = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.search);

        final EditText searchaddress = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.locationsearch);

        search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //FIND LOCATION BY ADDRESS

                if (searchaddress.getText().toString() != null && !searchaddress.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

                    new GetAddressPositionTask(getApplicationContext()).execute(searchaddress.getText().toString());

                    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(position, 13));
                    CameraUpdate zoom = CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15);
                    map.animateCamera(zoom);

                    //Marker marker = null;
                    map.clear();
                    //marker.setPosition(position);
                    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .title("Shop")
                            .snippet("Is this the right location?")
                            .position(position))
                            .setDraggable(true);

                    // map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new PopupAdapter(getLayoutInflater()));
                    map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(MapsActivity.this);
                    map.setOnMarkerDragListener(MapsActivity.this);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter an address!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

---

The process I do is open MapsActivity, then type a correct address and trying to display it.
The result is that the position doesn't being changed BUT i don't get in logcat the message `NULL?﹕ position is empty!` after clicking the button.

---

This is the logcat from the first time I navigate to MapsActivity and then click a button that calls the class:

```
02-24 20:55:35.133    5907-5907/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all E/Spinner﹕ setPopupBackgroundDrawable: incompatible spinner mode; ignoring...
02-24 20:55:35.143    5907-5907/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all E/Spinner﹕ setPopupBackgroundDrawable: incompatible spinner mode; ignoring...
02-24 20:55:35.143    5907-5907/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all E/Spinner﹕ setPopupBackgroundDrawable: incompatible spinner mode; ignoring...
02-24 20:55:35.223    5907-5907/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 47 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-24 20:55:36.775    5907-5907/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all time:42579264
02-24 20:55:36.865    5907-5907/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all I/x﹕ Making Creator dynamically
02-24 20:55:37.265    5907-5907/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Google Play services client version: 6587000
02-24 20:55:37.285    5907-5907/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all I/Google Maps Android API﹕ Google Play services package version: 6776034
02-24 20:55:38.406    5907-5907/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.pm.PackageManager.getPackageInstaller, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.ew.c
02-24 20:55:38.406    5907-5907/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 441: Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;.getPackageInstaller ()Landroid/content/pm/PackageInstaller;
02-24 20:55:38.406    5907-5907/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000f
02-24 20:55:39.117    5907-5907/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all D/NULL?﹕ position is empty!
02-24 20:55:39.377    5907-5907/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 57 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
02-24 20:55:39.517    5907-5907/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all I/libblt_hw﹕ Library opened (handle = 0, fd = 100)
02-24 20:55:39.788    5907-5907/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@424fec18 time:42582274
02-24 20:55:41.970    5907-5912/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all I/dalvikvm﹕ Jit: resizing JitTable from 4096 to 8192
02-24 20:55:47.946    5907-6133/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all I/GEOCODE_background﹕ lat/lng: (64.963051,-19.020835)
02-24 20:55:47.946    5907-5907/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all I/GEOCODE﹕ lat/lng: (64.963051,-19.020835)
02-24 20:55:47.946    5907-5907/guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:guide_me_for_all.guide_me_for_all time:42590434
```

Comment: Getting value in `Log.i("GEOCODE", result.toString());` ?

Comment: Yes I am getting the correct value in the logcat @ρяσѕρєяK.

Comment: @Ranjith I posted it.
@user370305 my onCreate() has really unnecessary things in it. This is the part that is related to getting the value:
 `if (getIntent() != null) {
                Intent intent = getIntent();

                position_from_address = intent.getStringExtra("latlng");

                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), position_from_address, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); `

Comment: @marialena: not getting `Log.d("NULL?", "position is empty!");` in log?

Comment: I am getting this message in logcat only in the first onCreate (before even clicking the button). I toasted the position after calling the method in the class I created and the position value is the one I initialized before onCreate. So, the value was not being changed in the `if (getIntent() != null) {`. Right now I changed the putExtra of the class that was string to be parcelable but nothing changed. The pin is in the same location I initialized

Comment: `I am getting this message in logcat only in the first onCreate (before even clicking the button).` This line get me confuse.

Comment: Okay sorry. What I mean is  that my application has a navigation drawer. So when I click in the AddShopFragment for example, there is a button that when I click it I navigate to MapsActivity. By the time I click this button, I am geetting the message in logcat that the position is empty, which is logical because I hadn't called yet the function from the class I created.

Comment: @marialena: store `position` value in `SharedPreferences` because probably you are moving from `MapsActivity` Activity to other that's why not getting same value again. store value in `SharedPreferences`

Comment: When I press the search button from MapsActivity, I call the function GetAddressPositionTask of the class and the result must be returned to MapsActivity. in the check about if getIntent of the result is null, I don't get the message in logcat that the position is empty, but the position does not changed from the one I initialized.
@ρяσѕρєяK let me check that

Comment: @marialena - You are in `MapsActivity ` calling  `GetAddressPositionTask` from a Search Button's `onClick()` within same MapsActivity and then now you are again start `MapsActivity (which is same activity)` from `onPostExecute()` of Task. Right?

Comment: Exactly @user370305. I just want to return the position (LatLng) back to MapsActivity, so that I can display it in map

Comment: Ohhh... So why are you calling same activity from AsyncTask again, Just update map on `onPostExecute()` That's it. This is the problem of your code.

Comment: @marialena: start Activity as `this.mainContxt.finish();  this.mainContxt.startActivity(i);` from `onPostExecute`

Comment: Simple, create a constructor of your AsyncTask pass  reference of `map` in that and in `onPostExecute()` just setPosition with new lat long.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK - I have doubt, as MapsActivity is always treated as new Activity as OP has set flags for it.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I can't do that, It doesn't recognize the `finish()` function.  @user370305 In MapsActivity, I am returning the last position to the AddShopFragment() so that I can save it to database with the other data. So, it's a bit complicated. I have to return it somehow and use this position.

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK If I don't put flags, some exceptions occurred. I searched about it and in some SO posts suggested those 2 flags.

Comment: Yes, You can update your database after completion of AsyncTask. actually, your problem is in your search button's click `map.setPostion() ` called with old position value before AsyncTask complete calculation of new values of position. So the best way is put the rest of code line of search button click (after AsyncTask's excute()) in `onPostExecute()` of AsyncTask()`

Comment: @marialena - What is `AsyncTask` means? to run code asynchronously, so your next code line immediately executed before AsyncTask's `doInBackground()` complete its work.

Comment: I am goig to try it tomorrow right after I complete some other universities tasks. Thanks for your help till now (both of you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

some bit confusing code and explanation,

Lets go with step wise.

**Step 1:** Update your MapsActivity's onCreate()

Like,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}
```

As here Intent is not required as you are only calling `MapsActivity` within same `MapsActivity`. We will update map in `onPostExecute()` of Activity then no need to start Activity again.

**Step 2:** Create Constructor for `GetAddressPositionTask` with `GoogleMap map` parameter to update your map position in `onPostExecute()` of `GetAddressPositionTask`. And `onPostExecute()`

Like,

```
public class GetAddressPositionTask extends
        AsyncTask<String, Integer, LatLng> {

  GoogleMap googleMap;
  LatLng mapPosition;

  GetAddressPositionTask(GoogleMap map, LatLng position)
  {
   googleMap = map;
   mapPosition = position;
  }
    //...
@Override
    public void onPostExecute(LatLng result) {

     if(result != null)
     {
       Log.i("GEOCODE", result.toString());
       mapPosition =  result;

        googleMap.clear();
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .title("Shop")
                            .snippet("Is this the right location?")
                            .position(mapPosition))
                            .setDraggable(true);
      }
   }
}
```

**Step 3:** How the search Button's `onClick()` look like, No extra code required,

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   //FIND LOCATION BY ADDRESS

   if (searchaddress.getText().toString() != null && !searchaddress.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {

          GetAddressPositionTask addressTask = new GetAddressPositionTask(map, position);
          addressTask.execute(searchaddress.getText().toString());

  } else {
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter an address!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
}
```

Comment: It's working great and the location is being displayed in map correctly. Thank you very much for this. But may I ask you... is there a way to give this location back to MapsActivity or there is no way that can make it work? Because that position the last location that we obtain from the class, I had to pass it to another activity and fragment too, different from MapsActivity so that I can save it.

Comment: @marialena - Store your location in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) and you can access it with any application components with Context..

Comment: @marialena - Happy coding..! Available with @ and my username . :)